# How to call window resize event jquery before page load mangento 2

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to call this function before page load rendring but its only fire  after page load  can somebody help me.

```
$(window).on('load resize', function(){
    var win = $(this); //this = window

    if (win.width() <= 767)
    { 
        $('.logo').insertAfter('.panel.wrapper');
    }     
    else
    {
        $('.logo').insertAfter('.action.nav-toggle');
    }
});
```

How to call window resize event jquery before page load

Comment: You can put that script inside the function before closing `</body>`, starting with `var win = $(window);`....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trigger events on anything with jQuery:

```
$(window).trigger('resize');
```

Comment: Its working but after completing page loads only its working

Comment: You can use `.trigger` to run any functions attached to the `resize` or `click` or `scroll` or whatever event whenever you want to. `$(window).on('resize', function() {alert('Here!');}); /* --- */ $(window).trigger('resize');` would instantly alert "Here!".